# Is there any way i can draw vertical multiple lines in svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to get something like this [image]

i have tried using strokeDashoffset and strokeDasharray but i still can't get it, ik that i can draw multiple lines but i will have a script that will have to fill these lines

any ideas how can i make them? thanks

i don't know if you need it but here is what i tried:

```html
<svg id="edilRW8EQ5h1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 54 12.5" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision" text-rendering="geometricPrecision">                              
<path strokeDasharray="10, 10" strokeDashoffset="10" pathLength="500" d="M0,6.25h54v2.134695h-54L0,6.25" fill="white" stroke="#3f5787" stroke-width="0.5"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Please try this path instead: <path stroke-dasharray="1" d="M0,6.25h54" stroke="#3f5787" stroke-width="5" transform="skewX(-20)"/>. In order to achieve what you want you may need to use a gradient for the stroke.

Comment: oh i see, forgot about the skew, thank you i think i can figure it out now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks a lot like a [`<pattern>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern). Here I use the pattern on a `<rect>` and at the same time the `<rect>` also has a mask. The mask has a gradient that controls the the whiteness.

It looks a bit like a meter. The "value" of the meter can now be controlled by the value of the two stop elements in the gradient (here 76%).

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 50 8">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="p1" viewBox="0 0 6 10" width="5%" height="100%">
      <path transform="translate(4 0) rotate(10)" d="M 0 0 V 10"
        stroke-width="4" stroke="white" stroke-linecap="round"/>
    </pattern>
    <linearGradient id="g1" gradientTransform="rotate(1.5)">
      <stop offset="0" stop-opacity=".2" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="76%" stop-opacity="1" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="76%" stop-opacity=".2" stop-color="white" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-opacity=".2" stop-color="white" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect width="50" height="8" fill="url(#g1)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="50" height="8" fill="black"/>
  <rect width="50" height="8" fill="url(#p1)" mask="url(#m1)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: it looks cool, thank you i finally understood how to make it